# HTML Code in Google Search Description/Snippet

Tags: google-search, html

When googleing for a certain keyword, Google will list our site along with this description:

> Wie die Spitzenforschung im globalen Dorf abläuft, zeigt das neue Globe. ETH Zürich, Globe Magazin, 1/16 ... width="600" height="849" alt="">. Zur Agentur ...

Since there's no ... before "Zur Agentur", I'm expecting this code to stand right before "Zur Agentur" in HTML.

Our site is lazy loading images and using fallback images inside `<noscript>` tags:

```
<noscript>
  <img src="…" width="600" height="849" alt="">
</noscript>
<p><a href="/agentur">Zur Agentur</a></p>
```

Is Google failing to interpret the content of the  tag as HTML?

Comment: Goolge fully understand `<noscript>` and other HTML tags. Google rewrites titles and descriptions based on what people are using. Is it possible the keyword your searching for is the filename of the image? You should also fill in all your ALT tags for both users and search engines. You should also correct the serious issue of having a css file outside of `<head>` and even`<html>` this appears at the bottom of your site.

Comment: @SimonHayter thanks for your comment. The search keywords are currently "Agentur Zürich". `alt` attributes are to be left empty if you cannot provide any additional information. CSS outside <html> was a suggestion from Google Page Speed. We'll replace it by JS loading.

Comment: If the keyword was in the filename, the filename would be part of the description on Google'? SERP, which is not the case.

Comment: No... you need to input the ALT tag, the filename should not be treated as a search engine description.